# adding "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj" into xcode4.0

Tags: ios4

I just start using Xcode 4 and i'm trying to draw graph by adding "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj" into my project But when i did this i would not get "libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a".Could anyone tell me how to use it in Xcode 4.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting `libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a` by dragging and dropping, then go to

> project->targets->build phases->add link with libraries->libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a

Alternatively, go to

> project build settings->library search paths

then set the path to your `libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a` file. To do so, right-click on your lib file, then click on

> get info->copy the path